# Hibernate isInitialized outside of session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Is there any way to check whether an entity's lazy collection attribute is initialized once we're outside the Transactional session?

For example, my `Job` entity has a lazy association to a list of `Step`, which is only sometimes initialized. In my controller, I would like to know if the steps collection has been initialized, although I'm met with a `LazyInitializationException` instead:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: Unable to perform requested lazy initialization [com.overflow.stack.Job.steps] - no session and settings disallow loading outside the Session
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.EnhancementHelper.throwLazyInitializationException(EnhancementHelper.java:199) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.EnhancementHelper.performWork(EnhancementHelper.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.loadAttribute(LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.fetchAttribute(LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.handleRead(LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.readObject(AbstractInterceptor.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at com.overflow.stack.Job.$$_hibernate_read_steps(Job.java) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.overflow.stack.Job.getSteps(Job.java:135) ~[classes/:?]
    ...
```

```java
@Entity
public class Step {
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Job {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "job", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<Step> steps = new ArrayList<>();

  public List<Step> getSteps() {
    return steps;
  }
  ...
}

@Controller
public JobController {
  public List<Step> getJobSteps(Long id) {
    // Transactional service class method which fetches by id (does not initialize steps)
    Job job = jobService.getJob(id);

    if (Hibernate.isInitialized(job.getSteps())) { // Throws LazyInitializationException
      return job.getSteps();
    } else {
      return List.of();
    }
  }
}

@Service
@Transactional
public JobService {
  @Autowired JobRepository jobRepo;

  public Job getJob(Long id) {
    Job job = jobRepo.findById(id).get();
    Hibernate.unproxy(job);
    return job;
  }
}
```

In this case, the exception is thrown when it attempts to execute `job.getSteps()` in the `if` statement.
I know that the session is closed by the time I leave the service call (the controller is not `Transactional`), although I'm wondering if there's any way to check if it's been initialized, or is the getSteps() method completely out of reach at that point?

Answer (score 0):

`Hibernate.isInitialized(job.getSteps())` shouldn't throw `LazyInitializationException` (LIE).

`job.getSteps()` returns a proxy, to have LIE you need to call a method of a proxy, for example `job.getSteps().size()`.

`job.getSteps()` can throw LIE, if `job` is a proxy itself.

Anyway using entities as a response of REST API is a very bad idea. You will have a lot of issues with that.

Better to use `JobEntity` for an entity and `Job` for DTO. Just convert from `JobEntity` to `Job` on the service level. You can call `Hibernate.isInitialized(jobEntity.getSteps())` on the service level and set an empty collection for the steps to the `Job`.

**To unproxy entity**

`Hibernate.unproxy()` returns a different object (not the same proxy). Also keep in mind that "If the proxy is uninitialized, it automatically triggers an initialization".

```java
public Job getJob(Long id) {
    Job job = jobRepo.findById(id).get();
    return Hibernate.unproxy(job, Job.class);
}
```

Comment: In this case, `job` is indeed a proxy, although it's been initialized/unproxied in the service level, so wouldn't that make the `getSteps()` method accessible? All it does is `return steps`, so I'm not calling any further methods on it. I've added some more details about the stack trace to show that the exception is actually throw in the `getSteps()` call and not in the `Hibernate.isInitialized()` call.
As for the DTO pattern, my example is simplified, but I'm working with a larger codebase so changing the REST serialization wouldn't be feasible

Comment: @theGirrafish Please add to the question how you unproxy `job`.

Comment: I've added an example snippet of how I unproxy the entity after fetching from the db